# 対象の EC2 内から情報を取得し、そのEC2についている Role に policy を付与したい

Tags: itamae, aws-iam, aws-sdk

itamae で構築対象のEC2サーバーについてる EC2 Role に特定のポリシーを付与したいです

どうするのがスマートかわからないので
とりあえずリモートの hostname を取得して
ローカルで aws-sdk-ruby で同じ hostname になる ec2 インスタンスを探して

```
ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new(region: 'ap-northeast-1')
ec2.instances.each do |i|
  if i.private_dns_name == hostname
```

その中の role_id を取得して
その role_id から role オブジェクトを作って
atttach policy を呼ぶ
というかなり回りくどい方法しか思いつかないのですが
スマートな方法はないでしょうか

またその場合リモートの hostname の結果をローカルの ruby 上で取得したいのですが
itamae でリモートのシェル実行結果を取得することはどうすれば実現できますか

#### 追記

ec2_instance に IamInstanceProfile というプロパティはあるのですが
Role に関しては出てきません
AWS Console には Role が表示されるんですが
この EC2 Role はどうやって取得すればいいですか

Comment: 質問の操作が実現できたと仮定します。当該EC2が攻撃を受け侵入された場合に攻撃者は任意のポリシーを付与してAWSを自由に操作できることになってしまいますが、セキュリティとして大丈夫なのでしょうか？

Comment: たしかにEC2内で実行するコマンドで付与できてしまうとリスクがありますね。そうなるとitamae を実行するインスタンスには強い権限をもたせてるので、回りくどくても対象サーバーからEC2を特定する情報だけをレシピ側で取得してpolicyをアタッチするしかないでしょうか…　いずれにしてもitamaeでホストの実行結果を取得する方法がわからずに困ってるところなのですが…